# Kxml2 How to convert xml to wbxml?

Tags: java, activesync, kxml2, wbxml

I have configured the tag_tables. But the issues it that conversion is not happening for the namespaces.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used kxml2 for this, but have some [Java code](http://code.google.com/p/corporateaddressbook/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/net/vivekiyer/GAL/wbxml) that should do the trick.